# Laravel: time dependent pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

### Following Scenario

I have an order table, which has among other things an order type:

**Table: orders**

```
id
order_type_id
...
```

Now I can add articles to an order via an order_articles pivot table but that's not the point.

**Table: order_articles**

```
order_id
article_id
amount
...
```

Additionally I have an pivot table between order types and articles which defines things like the price of this article for different order types.

**Table: article_order_types**

```
article_id
order_type_id
price
...
```

### The Problem

Now I have the new requirement that the article order type price is time-dependent, which basically means the this pivot table needs two start and end datetime columns.

So far so good but I struggle a bit with the Laravel relations in that case.
Currently I think of something like the following relations:

**Article.php (Model)**

```
    public function orderTypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( OrderType::class , 'article_order_types' )->withPivot( [ 'price' , 'start' , 'end' ] );
    }


    public function currentOrderType()
    {
        return $this->orderTypes()->wherePivot( 'start' , '<=' , today() )->wherePivot( 'end' , '=' , null );
    }
```

This has several problems for example the `currentOrderType()` relations returns still an collection whereas I would need the current model directly.
And I am not sure if that's in general the right direction in which I am going here. I would appreciate any recommendations and hints.

Answer (score 0):

You are going the correct way. Please try the below one.

```
public function currentOrderType()
{
    return $this->orderTypes()->wherePivot( 'start' , '<=' , today() )->wherePivot( 'end' , '<=' , today() )->firstOrFail();
}
```

It will be better if your pass a default amount when the record is not found.

```
 public function currentOrderType()
{
   $defaultOrderType = ......;
   $orderType = $this->orderTypes()->wherePivot( 'start' , '<=' , today() )->wherePivot( 'end' , '<=' , today() )->first();
    return ($orderType) ? $orderType : $defaultOrderType;
}
```

Note:
The combination of the start, end and order_type_id columns must be unique.